In appscript, I have to do vlookup for ID (Form Responses 1)if this ID is availablein Sheet1 then it is there it has to send mail as "True" or "False"
My problem is For example, Assume two persons are filling the google form, Firt person filled the form in that ID is matching with sheet 1, so the mail sent to his mail id as "True" and next the second person filled the form that time mail is sent him as "False" and also sent to the first person as "True" again,
I know it because of the range i selected from F2:F it checking again and again, i want to increment the cell everytime the mail sent to particular person, can anyone can help in this?
